# MongoDB: how to persist selected document from collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm not how to best solve my fairly basic problem.

I have a Collection of "emoji" Documents in my database. At any given time, there is one (and only one) "selected" emoji Document. This is determined and updated by the application. How can I persist the information of which one is selected to the database?

**Approach 1:**
Add a new Collection to hold this kind of metadata of the emoji collection? I'm thinking it would hold a single document with a reference to the currently selected emoji document. This seems to hurt the OO design. A whole collection, with a single document, to hold a single property. But it does have flexibility to add more metadata.

**Approach 2:**
Add a new boolean field to each emoji Document indicating whether or not it is the current selected emoji. This seems like a lot of extra info to track for each Document, when only one should have a true value. I would also be concerned with maintaining consistency.

I know I'm not the first person to have this issue, but I couldn't find a solution this is as a general case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is schemaless so you can just add the boolean field to the currently selected emoji and remove it when the selection changes. You should add a parse unique index to make querying this field faster. You could set the field using this syntax:

```
db.emojis.update({name:"b"},{$set:{selected:true}})
```

And simply unset it like this:

```
db.emojis.update({name:"b"},{$unset:{selected:""}})
```

You could create the following parse unique index to ensure there is only ever one field with `selected:true`

```
db.emojis.createIndex( { selected: 1 } , { sparse: true, unique: true } )
```